# mongodb won't start mongod -> error dbpath does not exists, but the path does exit

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm having trouble starting my mongodb. I've installed it yesterday and even have put some records in the db. But later when I wanted to go further with the project and tried to start the db again it wouldn't start.

this is what I tried in my cmd (ps I'm using Windows 8 and i've turned off my firewall)
c:\mongo\bin>mongod --> error dbpath(\data\db) does not exist

c:\mongo\bin>mongo --> failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 reason: errno:10061

c:\mongo\bin>mongo.exe --> failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 reason: errno:10061

c:\mongo\bin>mongod.exe --> error dbpath(\data\db) does not exist

So generaly , it just keeps saying that the dbpath doesn't exist , but it does because in my c:\mongo\bin map i have a map data and in that map there is a map db

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to explicitly specify path via --dbpath option or in config file, like this:

```
 mongod --dbpath c:\data\db
```

Comment: so the data\db folder is not aloud to be in my mongo\bin folder or  ?

I've also tried to specify the path with c:\mongo\bin\data\db
then he starts doing stuf but stops at "waiting for connections on port 27017" for a long time and finaly he stops at connections:0 ...

Comment: What is wrong with it!? You are starting db server, it is waiting for incoming connections. Open another console window, and you could reach it.

Comment: alright that was the step that I forgot, in the new console window, so stupid of me ... I've been searching for over a day for this simple solution 
Thank you very much! And sorry for wasting your time with my stupidty, it's my first time using mongo and node.js

Answer (score 1):

worked for me to make a map in windows explorer and then run mongod.
But it needs to be the drive where mongo is installed c:\data\db and not in for example e:\data\db